# Android Location foreground service calling

Tags: java, android, multithreading, location, foreground-service

I am using android foreground service for continuous location updates that starts when user clicks a button. My question is what if the user presses the button twice? Will there be two foreground process running? If so, how to check whether foregroundservice running already or not.

So that I can apply a condition before calling the foreground service. Please let me know if there a way.

Answer (score 0):

Services are singletons-  only one will exist at a time.  However, it will call onStartCommand again with a new Intent if you call startService or startForegroundService again.  So make sure that call won't cause you to rerequest location updates if you already have.

Comment: I got it now. thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your service is running or not by using this function:

```kotlin
private fun isMyServiceRunning(serviceClass: Class<*>): Boolean {
        val manager = getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        for (service in manager.getRunningServices(Int.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.name == service.service.className) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

If your service is not running start the service:

```kotlin
if (!isMyServiceRunning(MyService::class.java) {
    startService(...)
}
```